# odoo 15 Unstyled Login page when db selected and show blanket page

Tags: python, odoo, erp, odoo-15

im runing odoo 15 on ubuntu 20.04 in vm in proxmox

odoo was running correctly and out of nothing my database wont work

i have database a and GData  they were both working fine

now only db a working but db GData  not working

***there is two problems***

> 1-when selected db login page showed unstyled
>
> 2-when enter login it shows blanket page

i tried to change my url to login as dev

```
ip:port/web?debug=assets
```

but the problem remain

here is the error that appears when i select db GData  and redirected to login page

```
2023-04-18 00:23:03,802 94651 INFO GData odoo.addons.base.models.ir_attachment: _read_file reading /root/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/GData/0e/0ee951439c6eb9f6df65166aa4dda9b8351ecd0e 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 886, in get
    return field_cache[record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 290

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1057, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 889, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(290,).datas'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 886, in get
    return field_cache[record._ids[0]]
KeyError: 290

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/fields.py", line 1057, in __get__
    value = env.cache.get(record, self)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/api.py", line 889, in get
    raise CacheMiss(record, field)
odoo.exceptions.CacheMiss: 'ir.attachment(290,).raw'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_attachment.py", line 119, in _file_read
    with open(full_path, 'rb') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/root/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/GData/0e/0ee951439c6eb9f6df65166aa4dda9b8351ecd0e'
2023-04-18 00:23:03,803 94651 INFO GData werkzeug: 172.16.10.43 - - [18/Apr/2023 00:23:03] "GET /web/assets/290-40435a7/web.assets_frontend_minimal.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - 3 0.001 0.004
2023-04-18 00:23:25,545 94651 INFO GData odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Starting job `payment: post-process transactions`. 
2023-04-18 00:23:25,551 94651 INFO GData odoo.addons.base.models.ir_cron: Job `payment: post-process transactions` done.
```

Comment: Looks like your asset files are corrupt, deleted or without access. You should check the path `/root/.local/share/Odoo/filestore/GData`, because there should be the data/attachments for your database GData.